# Is there an easier method to implement the SQL statement "INSERT INTO" to an entire table without manually specifying table columns?

Tags: sql, database, syntax

A couple of days ago I took it upon myself to learn the fundamentals of SQL. While doing so, I came across the statement `INSERT INTO` which is used to insert records into a table or to specific columns. Imagine I have a table with 50 columns, let's name this table `My_table`. If I were to implement the `INSERT INTO` statement to `My_table` it would look something like this (please correct me if my syntax is wrong):

```
INSERT INTO My_table (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4,...)
VALUES (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4,...)
```

This list of columns would continue until I have specified all 50. Is there an alternative method to specifying all columns?

What I had in mind was code that looked something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO My_table (*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (value_1, value_2...)
```

Keep in mind that the order in which you put said values is the order of the column, i.e. you had a table consisting of a CHAR(5) column called "name" and a BIGINT column called logindate in this exact order you would do

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ("bobby", 12345678);
```